# Reference Custom Date Format In Cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to reference the custom date value in a cell (N6 = 2019.08.01) for a filepath however, Excel is returning what appears to be the Excel code value for that date (i.e., 43678)

My formula is '=D:\Items\Price\August\N6'

My filepath returned should be 
    D:\Items\Price\August\**2019.08.01**

I'm returning 
    D:\Items\Price\August\**43678**

I've tried a bunch of Excel functions to keep this custom format, but am having no luck so I was wondering if anyone had an idea how to make it keep the custom format for referencing. I'm sure this is a simple solution, but I'm going crazy searching for this answer lol.

Functions used:

=N6: 2019.08.01

=DateValue(N6): #VALUE!

=Value(N6): 43678

Thanks for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use TEXT:

```
="D:\Items\Price\August\" & TEXT(N6,"yyyy.mm.dd")
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix! I'm realizing now that when i tried TEXT() last I forgot the parenthesis for the format... I tried upvoting, but too much of a newb for Stack to allow me so please take my heartfelt thanks and hope you have an amazing weekend!

Comment: @HTMLame after the question is 15 minutes old you can click the check mark by the answer to mark it as correct.